# How to reduce padding-top of content area on the Stack Overflow website

Tags: css, tampermonkey

I want to reduce the size of `padding-top` for the `content` area of the Stack Overflow website - using some custom CSS code applied using Tampermonkey.

The element I'm talking about is called `div#content` and currently `padding-top` is set to `24px`. I want to reduce just this padding, but keeping the others the same.

Here is a minimal template using Tampermonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        stackoverflow_reducepaddingtop
// @match       *://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( ` ` );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to:

- [How to change a class CSS with a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385698/how-to-change-a-class-css-with-a-greasemonkey-tampermonkey-script)
  and
- [*Understanding Style Precedence in CSS:*](http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)

Your script was complete except for the actual CSS.  So finished it is:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        stackoverflow_reducepaddingtop
// @match       *://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( `#content {padding-top: 0px !important;}` );
```

---

---

Note that the `!important;` flag may not be needed for that exact selector (right now), but other CSS you could use does require it in a *Stylus* or `GM_addStyle` scenario. (Especially when using `document-start`.)