# Tampermonkey: Remove font-weight style from TD tags

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to remove the results from Wikipedia's AFL/VFL season pages (eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992_AFL_season#Round_1)

I've got rid of the 'def.', 'def. by' and the scores, which is pretty good going considering I started learning to write Tampermonkey scripts about half an hour ago. But I can't figure out a way to remove the bolding on the winning team's name. In the source, it's this:

```
<td style="font-weight: bold;">
```

The script I've got so far is this:

```
(function(NoWinner) {
  var els = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
  for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
    var el = els[i];
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/def.*/gi, '');
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\s\(\d{1,3}\)/gi, '');
  }

  NoWinner();
})();
```

I'm just not sure how to replace the actual tag, rather than the contents of the element.

Comment: The IIFE isn't being called with anything, but then you try to call `NoWinner`, the argument, at the bottom - what's that intended to do? (or is that just a typo or something?) It'll currently throw a TypeError

Comment: Like I said I started learning this half an hour ago, but the script as posted works for me.

Comment: You *should* be getting `Execution of script '0 <userscript name>' failed! NoWinner is not a function` - I'm not sure what you're trying to call there

Comment: Neither am I, I just followed the formatting used in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385698/how-to-change-a-class-css-with-a-greasemonkey-tampermonkey-script

Comment: Ah, I see it. I put the name inside the parentheses. Yeah, no idea why it works then. But it does, so I'll leave it that way haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the bold td elements directly and remove the style propterty "font-weight":

```js
const allBoldTd = document.querySelectorAll('td[style*="font-weight: bold"]');


allBoldTd.forEach(td => td.style.removeProperty('font-weight'))
```