# How to remove or hide every <p class="description"> and the border-bottom thing with tampermonkey?

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm new at scripts, htmls, css stuffs. Basically just don't know anything about it.   (If I missing some tags, I'm sorry. D:)

And I'm trying to make a script to remove/hide the description and the border-bottom for 1 week but still no progress.   (It's a browser game called sploop.io and I want to make the hat menu look better.)

Images: `<p class="description">` => https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JhMs.jpg , Border-bottom => https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDN9g.jpg

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Sploop.io Better Hat Menu
// @version      0.1
// @description  Better Hat Menu
// @author       s
// @match        https://sploop.io/
// @icon         none
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
'use strict';

document.getElementById('da-left').style = "display:none;"
document.getElementById('da-right').style = "display:none;"
document.getElementById('bottom-content').style = "display:none;"
document.getElementById('alsoTryLink').style = "display:none;"
document.getElementById('cross-promo').style = "display:none;"
document.getElementById('google_play').style = "display:none;"
document.getElementById('iogames').style = "display:none;"
document.getElementById("hat-menu").style = "display: flex; opacity: 1; height: 320px; width: 400px; box-shadow: 0px 0px; border: 0px solid; border-radius: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; background: rgba(40, 45, 34, 0.3);";
document.getElementById("hat_menu_content").style = "width: 400px; background: rgb(20 20 20 / 0%); box-shadow: inset 0 5px 0 rgb(20 20 20 / 0%); margin: 20px 0 0px 0; border: 0px solid #141414";

})();
```

And this is the code that I using right now for the hat menu, I just need to remove/hide the description and the border-bottom thing then it's done but I don't know how to make it so I came here and ask for help on how to remove/hide them.

Comment: Hi there, pls attach the code in text form into your post

Answer (score 1):

Simply do something like this:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://sploop.io/
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=sploop.io
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle(`
  .description {
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }

  .menu-item {
    border-bottom: none !important;
  }
`);
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19392142/11613622